# Relay readyState ABORT on first setVariables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

I have a `Relay` container that defines the following initialVariables and fragments:

```
  initialVariables: {
    enableExistingThreadQuery: false,
    recipientValue: null,
    contactId: null,
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on viewer {
        organization @include(if: $enableExistingThreadQuery) {
          existingThread (recipientValue: $recipientValue, contactId: $contactId) {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  }
```

So I need this query to run when I set **recipientValue** and **contactId**:

```
relay.setVariables({
  recipientValue: ...,
  contactId: ...,
  enableExistingThreadQuery: true,
}, readyState => {
  console.log(readyState);
});
```

The **first** time I set these variables, this successfully runs the query and we get the data on the frontend. However, **readyState** only logs once with the following sequence of events:

- NETWORK_QUERY_START
- CACHE_RESTORE_START
- ABORT

With no errors, but `done` and `ready` are both **false**.

The **second** time I make this call to `relay.setVariables` it loads the data from the cache and `done` and `ready` are both **true**.

What might be causing setVariables to abort the first time it's called, even when the data is still successfully returned?

Answer (score 0):

In your browser's debugger, set a breakpoint on the following line in `GraphQLQueryRunner.js` (it should be near the end) to find out what is aborting your request:

`readyState.update({ aborted: true }, [{ type: 'ABORT' }]);`

The most likely reason is that you have another `setVariables`/`forceFetch` call while the current query is not done.